# SwiftUI: dynamic view dispatch? Polymorphic views?

Tags: swift, swiftui, polymorphism, dispatch

I'm a Swift/SwiftUI beginner and am trying to make a program that visualizes a few different types of data (w/ swift 5.7, targeting macOS).

I have a root "`Data`" protocol, and a few different protocols for its subtypes. A simplified example:

```swift
protocol Data {}
protocol HasA: Data { var a: String {get} }
protocol HasB: Data { var b: String {get} }

struct StructA: HasA { let a: String = "I am A"}
struct StructB: HasB { let b: String = "I am B"}
```

Now, I'd like to have a view that picks a visualization strategy based on the specific type of data it receives. This doesn't work, but here's how I'd write in a dynamic language:

```swift
struct DataView: View {
    let data: Data 
    var body: some View {
        // this doesn't actually work
        if data is HasA {
            ViewA(data) //  ERROR: type 'any Data' does not conform to the expected type 'HasA'
        } else if data is  {
            ViewDefault(data)
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried many, many different ways to accomplish this, without success. So clearly, there's something fundamentally wrong with my strategy. How should I be approaching this problem? Generics? Using concrete classes only? More existential types?

**Some things I've tried that didn't work**

1. Generics in many different forms, all of which ended up with `type 'any Data' does not conform to expected type 'Data'` errors.
2. Protocol extensions of the form:

   ```swift
   extension Data { func getView() -> View { ...} }
   extension HasA { func getView() -> View { ...} }
   ```

   This *will* compile, but at runtime, it only calls the `Data.getView()` implementation, not the `HasA.getView()` implementation.
3. Adding a required `func getView() -> any View` method to the `Data` protocol, and then implementing it on the concrete classes. This leads to `Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'` errors.
4. Runtime dispatch via protocol conformance - this is what's in the example above, i.e., `if data is HasA {return ViewA(data)}`. I didn't really expect this to work, and it doesn't - the compiler complains about protocol conformance.

**Edited to add**

In addition to @EDUsta's solution below, in my real production solution, I also had to **remove all associated types and generic parameters** from the data protocols that the view layer uses - otherwise downcasting wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current approach, at some point, you need to know the underlying type/protocol to act upon it. If you'd like to continue with this approach, this would work out of the box:

```swift
struct DataView: View {
    let data: Data
    var body: some View {
        switch data {
        case is HasA:
            ViewA(data: data as! HasA)
        default:
            EmptyView()
        }
        // or
        if let data = data as? HasA {
            ViewA(data: data)
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
```

The reason is, `is HasA` is not enough for a (smart) cast, like Kotlin.

I'd suggest another approach with SwiftUI though, `AnyView`! `AnyView` erases the type of the `View`, so you can combine this with your third approach:

```swift
protocol NVData {
    func getView() -> AnyView
}

protocol HasA: NVData {
    var a: String { get }
}

protocol HasB: NVData {
    var b: String { get }
}

extension HasA {
    func getView() -> AnyView {
        AnyView(ViewA(data: self))
    }
}

extension HasB {
    func getView() -> AnyView {
        AnyView(EmptyView())
    }
}

struct StructA: HasA { let a: String = "I am A" }
struct StructB: HasB { let b: String = "I am B" }

struct DataView: View {
    let data: any NVData
    var body: some View {
        data.getView()
    }
}

struct ViewA: View {
    let data: HasA

    var body: some View {
        Text(data.a)
    }
}
```

Deriving the `View` from the `Data` inverts the dependency, though. Something to keep in mind.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for this very clear answer! Looks like I need to go back and read the Protocols chapter of the Swift Book more carefully :)